# Tridiagonal band matrix, finding its inverse norm

Tags: linear-algebra

$$A_h = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots\\
& & \ddots & -1 \\
& & & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$

this matrix has size n-by-n. $h=\frac{1}{n+1}$. Find a constant $c$ independent of $h$ such that $||A_h^{-1}||_2 \leq c$ for $0<h<1$

I am trying to solve this problem (I believe the solution is supposed to be 1/4, but I am not getting that).

Here is my solution procedure:

$$||A_h^{-1}||_2 = \rho((A_h^{-1})^*A_{h}^{-1})^{0.5} = \rho(A_h^{-1})$$
Since $A_h^{-1}$ is hermitian, its inverse is also hermitian $(A_h^{-1})^*=A_h^{-1}$.

The spectral radius of $A_h^{-1}$ is the inverse of the minimum absolute eigenvalue of $A_h$
This is as far as I got, I can't figure out where the 1/4 came from. Any ideas?

Comment: See identity $(19)$ here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html. The eigenvalues of your matrix are not difficult to find.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have an expression for the eigenvalues (it is sinusoidal dependent on h). But I stlil do not obtain the 1/4.

Answer (score 2):

It is well-known that
$$ U_n(x) = \det\begin{pmatrix}2x & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2x & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\ 0&  0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2x\end{pmatrix} $$
hence the characteristic polynomial of the $n\times n$ matrix

$$A_n=\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\ 0&  0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

is $U_n\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{2}\right)$.
The roots of $U_n(x)$ occur at $x=\cos\frac{k\pi}{n+1}$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$, hence the eigenvalues of $A_n$ are given by:
$$ \lambda_k = 2\left(1-\cos\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right) = 4\sin^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+2}\right),\qquad k=1,2,\ldots,n.$$
So the smallest eigenvalue of $A_n$ behaves like $\frac{\pi^2}{(n+1)^2}$, while the largest is always $\leq 4$.

It follows that $\|A_n^{-1}\|_2$ **cannot** be bounded by an absolute constant, since it is $\Theta(n^2)$.