# Proving that ${n+3\choose 3} =\frac{n+2}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\csc^2\frac{k\pi}{n+2}$

Tags: combinatorics, trigonometry, summation, binomial-coefficients

Fancy physics predicts the equality
$${n+3\choose 3} =\frac{n+2}{2}\;\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\csc^2\frac{k\pi}{n+2}$$
which I can check (numerically and symbolically) for small $n$, but cannot prove for every $n$.

Does someone see an elegant way of doing this? Expressing $\csc$ in terms of exponentials allows one to see this as a sum involving roots of unity, but  I don't see how to proceed.

Comment: Why not write it as
$${n+1\choose 3} =\frac{n}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac1{\sin^2(i\pi/n)}?$$
Surely it must come from looking at the coefficients of a Chebyshev polynomial.

Comment: Physicists like their context, Shark. :)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, or $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sin^2(k\pi/n)} = \frac{n^2-1}{3}$$, or indeed $$H\left(\left\{1 - \cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}n\right) : 1 \le k < n \right\}\right) = \frac{6}{n+1}$$ where $H$ denotes the harmonic mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using parts of [this question and answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615072/computing-a-2-sum-k-1n-frac1z-k-12-and-sum-k-1n-cot2-left/)
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sin^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+2}\right)}=
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(1+\cot^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+2}\right)\right)=\\
n+1+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(\cot^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+2}\right)\right)=n+1+\frac{(n+1)n}{3}=\frac{(n+3)(n+1)}{3}$$

Note: Jack's answer, with a link to wikipedia, touches this [question/answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065615/prove-sum-k-1m-cot2-k-pi-2m1-m2m-1-3/) as well.

Comment: Beautiful! Nice and short.

Answer (score 4):

**Proof using linear algebra :**

Initial expression

$${m+3\choose 3} =\frac{m+2}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\sin\left(\tfrac{k\pi}{m+2}\right)^{-2},\tag{1}$$

can be transformed, by expressing ${m+3\choose 3}=\dfrac16(m+3)(m+2)(m+1)$ into :

$$\dfrac13(m+3)(m+1) =\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\sin\left(\tfrac{k\pi}{m+2}\right)^{-2},\tag{1'}$$

Let us separate cases $m$ even and $m$ odd.

**First case :** $m:=2n$.

In this case, expression (1') is equivalent (due to the property $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin(x)$) to :

$$\dfrac13(2n+3)(2n+1) =1+2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin\left(\tfrac{k\pi}{2(n+1)}\right)^{-2},\tag{1''}$$

which is itself equivalent to :

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{4 \sin\left(\tfrac{k\pi}{2(n+1)}\right)^2}=
\dfrac{n(n+2)}{6}\tag{2}$$

Consider the $n \times n$ tridiagonal matrix

$$D_n=\begin{pmatrix}2&-1&0&0&0&0&\cdots\\
-1&2&-1&0&0&0&\cdots\\
0&-1&2&-1&0&0&\cdots\\
0&0&-1&2&-1&0&\cdots\\
0&0&0&-1&2&-1&\cdots\\
0&0&0&0&-1&2&\cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&
\end{pmatrix}\tag{3}$$

The eigenvalues of $D_n$ are (see [Eigenvalues of tridiagonal symmetric matrix with diagonal entries 2 and subdiagonal entries 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/177957)) :

$$\lambda_k:=4 \sin\left(\tfrac{k\pi}{2(n+1)}\right)^2, \ \ k=1,2,\cdots n\tag{4}$$

Remark : matrix $D_n$ is the classical discretized version of the second derivative (with a minus sign) : see the "Neumann case" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative.

Let us now consider $E_n:=D_n^{-1}.$

For example :

$$E_6:=D_6^{-1}=\dfrac17\begin{pmatrix}
6&5&4&3&2&1\\
5&10&8&6&4&2\\
4&8&12&9&6&3\\
3&6&9&12&8&4\\
2&4&6&8&10&5\\
1&2&3&4&5&6
\end{pmatrix}\tag{5}$$

In these matrices, we just need the general fact that the *diagonal entries of $D_n$* obey the following formula :

$$E_{n,kk}=\tfrac{1}{n+1}k(n+1-k)\tag{6}.$$

(see Remark 1 below for a proof of (6))

Therefore :

$$trace(E)=\tfrac{1}{n+1}(\sum_{k=1}^n k(n+1-k))  \tag{7}$$

$$=\tfrac{1}{n+1}((n+1)\tfrac{n(n+1)}{2}-\tfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6})=\tfrac{n(n+2)}{6} \tag{8} $$

i.e., the RHS of (2).

Besides,

$$trace(E)=\sum \dfrac{1}{\lambda_k}$$ gives the LHS of (2), establishing this relationship.

Remarks :

1) Proof of formula (6). We need a first result which is rather easy to establish by recurrence : $\det(D_n)=n+1$. The cofactor associated with $E_{kk}$ is obtained by cancelling the $k$th row and $k$th column of $A_n$, giving a diagonal-by-block determinant with blocks $A_{k-1}$ and $A_{n-k)}$, whose determinants are resp. $k$ and $n-k+1$. This minor is to be divided by the determinant of $A_n,$ i.e., $n+1.$

2) In (8), we have used the classical formulas for the sum of the $n$ first integers, resp. the squares of the $n$ first integers.

3) A slightly different version of matrix $D$ and its remarkable inverse can be found as second example in the following question : [Looking for examples of Discrete / Continuous complementary approaches](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1774670) This is a typical case of an ill-conditionned matrix where a small perturbation (on the bottom right coefficient) gives a very different inverse.

4) Matrix $D_n$ is connected to Chebyshev polynomials of the 2nd kind $U_n$ ; see the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1770607

**Second case** : $m=2n-1$

Relationship (1') (to be established) is :

$$\dfrac16 n(n+1) =\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(4\sin\left(\tfrac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)\right)^{-2},\tag{9}$$

Let us consider now the $n \times n$ tridiagonal matrix :

$$\Delta_n:=\begin{pmatrix}2&1&&&&\\1&2&1&&&\\&1&2&1&&\\&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\&&&1&2&1\\&&&&1&3\end{pmatrix}$$

(please note the bottom right exceptional entry $3$).

It is not difficult to prove that $\Delta_n$ has the following eigenvalues :

$$\mu_k=4 \sin^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right),\qquad k=1\dots n$$

One can prove as well that $\det \Delta_n=2n+1$.

The inverse $\Gamma_n:=\Delta_n^{-1}$ is a structured matrix whose diagonal elements are :

$$\Gamma_{n,kk}=k\dfrac{1}{2n+1}k(2n+1-2k)=k-2\dfrac{1}{2n+1}k^2\tag{10}$$

(proof using the same arguments as those used in Remark 1 above.)

Using (10), the trace of $\Gamma$ is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k-2\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{6}$$

which is the LHS of (9), completing the proof.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I have now a proof covering the two cases (odd and even $m$).